# Delphi Package: "The following changes must be made..." never goes away

Tags: delphi, ide, package, custom-component

On one of my packages, which was adapted from another using Save-As and edit, I keep getting the following message (this is in Delphi 2007):

=======
The following changes must be made before this package can be compiled. 
Choose OK to apply these changes and continue compiling.

```
  Remove cmSizePanel_Reg.  
  Unit(s) cmSizePanel_Reg were found in required package cmExtRzPanel_D2007.
```

=======

I click OK, and it then proceeds to compile fine. This message, however, never goes away -- I get it every time I compile the package.

Here is the project source, using right-click, "View Source" to get there:

```
package cmBaseFrames_D2007;

{$R *.res}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO ON}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION ON}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO ON}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES OFF}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DESCRIPTION 'CM BaseFrames - Base Frames and related panels (TcmBaseFrame, etc)'}
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}

requires
  rtl,
  vcl,
  Rz30Ctls90,
  vclx,
  cmExtRzPanel_D2007;

contains
  cmBaseFrames_Reg in 'cmBaseFrames_Reg.pas',
  cmBaseFrameFrame in 'cmBaseFrameFrame.pas' {cmBaseFrame: TFrame},
  cmBaseSizeableFrameFrame in 'cmBaseSizeableFrameFrame.pas' {cmBaseSizeableFrame: TFrame};

end.
```

"cmSizePanel_Reg" isn't in the project anymore, and doesn't show up in teh Project Manager panel.  It would appear that it's "hiding" somewhere in one of the file Delphi uses for the package, but I'm not seeing where.  Any ideas how to stomp out this little inconvenience without having to complete re-create the package from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking through the XML of your .dproj for the package.  .dproj files have a knack for getting corrupted and becoming out of sync with the file list in the DPR, leading to strange problems like this.

Comment: That did it! -- Thanks.  Also ended up having to remove a DCR file manually as well, but this got me on the right track.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have this problem right now and deleting the .dproj didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Stale .dcp files maybe? They are the compliment to .BPL packages and contain descriptions about the BPL.

Comment: +1. This worked for me, once, then I had to actually remove some references to .dcps from the designtime project also.

Comment: dcp's iirc can contain the weakpackaged units of a package, and that makes them functionally equal to .dcu's.